# I try to delete some text in woocommerce php file but still display what i delete in the page

Tags: wordpress

i install new wordpress and then change dabase to the back up one, then i try to delete something in woocoommerce but it still show on the page,  so i delete that file, and see page still working, 
Already clear cache , but nothing change, so no idea how to do it?  who ever happen same as me please help?

even try with clean database and still not change

Comment: Have you tried to clean the permalink? Settings > Permalink > then click save changes.

Comment: Can you tell us for which file you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce single product page , i put the text in there , then i alredy delete text outnof that file but still showing, so i delete the whole woocommerce file  have only folder left , and it still work strange